# How correct filter data on yandex maps?

Tags: javascript, yandex, yandex-maps

I'm trying to filter data on yandex maps.
[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/DeepBlack/pen/zegQvR)

If the base station has several bands (2G, 3G and 4G), then it should be in the results if at least one of its band is in the filter.

**How correct filter data on yandex maps?**

I have listBoxControl with listBoxItems = ['2G', '3G', '4G']

My filter function looks like this:

```
function getFilterFunction(categories){
  return function(obj){
    let bsBands = obj.has_bands;
    /* How correct filter data? */
    return categories['2G'] && categories['3G'] && categories['4G'];
  }
}
```

GeoJSON looks like this:

```
{
"count": 4,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "region_prefix": "97",
        "cell_site_number": 1,
        "description": "",
        "address": "",
        "commissioning": "",
        "bs_id": "",
        "height_asl": 0,
        "bands": [
            {
                "name": "2G",
                "frequency": "900"
            },
            {
                "name": "2G",
                "frequency": "1800"
            },
            {
                "name": "3G",
                "frequency": "2100"
            },
            {
                "name": "4G",
                "frequency": "1800"
            },
            {
                "name": "4G TDD",
                "frequency": "2600"
            }
        ],
        "status": true,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [55.755815, 37.613]
        },
        "properties": {
            "balloonContentHeader": "balloonContentHeader",
            "balloonContentBody": "balloonContentBody",
            "balloonContentFooter": "balloonContentFooter",
            "clusterCaption": "clusterCaption",
            "hintContent": "hintContent",
            "iconCaption": "2G 3G 4G"
        },
        "has_bands": [
            "3G",
            "2G",
            "4G"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "region_prefix": "97",
        "cell_site_number": 2,
        "description": "",
        "address": "",
        "commissioning": "",
        "bs_id": "",
        "height_asl": 0,
        "bands": [
            {
                "name": "2G",
                "frequency": "900"
            },
            {
                "name": "2G",
                "frequency": "1800"
            },
            {
                "name": "3G",
                "frequency": "2100"
            },
            {
                "name": "4G",
                "frequency": "1800"
            },
            {
                "name": "4G TDD",
                "frequency": "2600"
            }
        ],
        "status": true,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [55.759, 37.613]
        },
        "properties": {
            "balloonContentHeader": "balloonContentHeader",
            "balloonContentBody": "balloonContentBody",
            "balloonContentFooter": "balloonContentFooter",
            "clusterCaption": "clusterCaption",
            "hintContent": "hintContent",
            "iconCaption": "2G 3G 4G"
        },
        "has_bands": [
            "3G",
            "2G",
            "4G"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "region_prefix": "97",
        "cell_site_number": 3,
        "description": "",
        "address": "",
        "commissioning": "",
        "bs_id": "",
        "height_asl": 0,
        "bands": [
            {
                "name": "3G",
                "frequency": "2100"
            }
        ],
        "status": true,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [55.7204, 37.6167]
        },
        "properties": {
            "balloonContentHeader": "balloonContentHeader",
            "balloonContentBody": "balloonContentBody",
            "balloonContentFooter": "balloonContentFooter",
            "clusterCaption": "clusterCaption",
            "hintContent": "hintContent",
            "iconCaption": "3G"
        },
        "has_bands": [
            "3G",
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "region_prefix": "97",
        "cell_site_number": 4,
        "description": "",
        "address": "",
        "commissioning": "",
        "bs_id": "",
        "height_asl": 0,
        "bands": [
            {
                "name": "4G",
                "frequency": "1800"
            },
            {
                "name": "4G TDD",
                "frequency": "2600"
            }
        ],
        "status": true,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [55.7704, 37.6119]
        },
        "properties": {
            "balloonContentHeader": "balloonContentHeader",
            "balloonContentBody": "balloonContentBody",
            "balloonContentFooter": "balloonContentFooter",
            "clusterCaption": "clusterCaption",
            "hintContent": "hintContent",
            "iconCaption": "4G"
        },
        "has_bands": [
            "4G"
        ]
    }]}
```

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: @molamk, according to documentation https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__setFilter-param-filterFunction

Filter function. Takes a single object added to ObjectManager. If the function returns true, the object will be processed. If false, the object will be excluded from further processing. A string can also be passed as a filter. 
For a filter, you can specify an expression that returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue myself. 
[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/DeepBlack/pen/zegQvR)

```
function getBand(e, i, a){
    let Band = this.valueOf();
    return e === Band; 
}

function getFilterFunction(categories){
    return function(obj){
        let bsBands = obj.has_bands;
        let has2G = bsBands.find(getBand, '2G');
        let has3G = bsBands.find(getBand, '3G');
        let has4G = bsBands.find(getBand, '4G');
        return (categories['2G'] && has2G) || (categories['3G'] && has3G) || (categories['4G'] && has4G);
    }
}
```